# How to combine docker creation and putting it in DEV Azure Container Registry?

Tags: azure, docker, mariadb, azure-pipelines

Here is my scenario:
I create a docker image from an SQL dump with the following commands, executed from command prompt:

```
docker pull mariadb:10.4.26
docker run --name test_smdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<some_password> -p 3306:3306 -d mariadb:10.4.26
docker exec -it test_smdb mariadb --user root -p<some_password>
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE smdb_dev;
docker exec -i test_smdb mariadb -uroot -p<some_password> smdb_dev --force < C:\smdb-dev.sql
```

But my task now is create a pipeline, that creates this docker image and puts it into the  Azure Container Registry

I found this link - Build and push Docker images to Azure Container Registry:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops

And i see that the result should be a yaml file like this:

```
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build job
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

But can someone show me how to combine the two things - the docker image creation and the putting it into the Azure Container Registry?

Comment: Did the answer posted on the ticket help you? If it helps, just as a remind of [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks for your kindness :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make a [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and put this in the repository.
The commands you specified at the top of your question should be your input
It could look something like this (just threw something together. probably wont work as is):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mariadb:10.4.26
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
run --name test_smdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<some_password> -p 3306:3306 -d mariadb:10.4.26
run MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE smdb_dev;
EXPOSE {mariadb port #}
```