# How to put creation of a docker image with maria DB dump into a docker file?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I executed docker commands in order to create a docker image, containing an maria DB SQL dump

```
docker pull mariadb:10.4.26
docker run --name test_smdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<some_password> -p 3306:3306 -d mariadb:10.4.26
docker exec -it test_smdb mariadb --user root -p<some_password>
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE smdb_dev;
docker exec -i test_smdb mariadb -uroot -p<some_password> smdb_dev --force < C:\smdb-dev.sql
```

But as this will have to be part of a Azure pipeline execution, i was advised to put all this in a docker file.

> 

[How to combine docker creation and putting it in DEV Azure Container Registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74809048/how-to-combine-docker-creation-and-putting-it-in-dev-azure-container-registry)

> 

Unfortunately i cannot find proper information how combine this all and especially the calling of an execution of a database creation from the docker file?

Comment: Could it be that the SQL dump did not include the "CREATE SCHEMA" when it was dumped?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how this is related to my question?

Comment: I'm not seeing the error message in this post when you attempt to run this.  But you can dump a DB with or without the Creation Schema, so it knows some defaults to use when creating the database versus just having the data its self.  i guess its not clear where the issue is you are having, so was offering just some advice that can commonly cause issues not related to Docker.

Comment: I do not get an error when running this. My problem is that i run this locally from a command prompt, but my task is to create Azure pipeline, which execute this. And in the link, that i gave, i was advised to put all this logic in a docker file, but i do not know how to do this and this is what i am asking here...

Comment: Ahh I see, okay, well my experience is with the actual equipment versus virtualized version so I wish I could give you more help.  I guess your question is more about how to get Docker to do this as you believe you have a DB that includes the create scheme and all that.   Godspeed my friend.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this as a sample and modify to your needs:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM mariadb:10.4.26

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD dummy-password
ENV MARIADB_DATABASE smdb-dev
COPY C:\smdb-dev.sql ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

ENTRYPOINT [ "docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

EXPOSE 3306

CMD [ "mysqld" ]
```

When you first time run a container, docker will restore your DB from the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder (it will restore it only if the persistent volume will be empty, otherwise it will just skip this step), in order to make this data persistent, you need to create a volume and attach it to mysql data folder on your container.

```
docker build *Dockerfile dir path* -t *image-name*
```

```
docker run -dp 3306:3306 *image-name*
```

Comment: technically don't need to duplicate the `ENTRYPOINT`, `EXPOSE` or `CMD` that would keep the mariadb defaults. `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` can be replaced with `MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD` too.